# Increase a value every second iteration

Tags: python

I want to increase a value every second iteration by a fixed value. The above code solves this, but I wonder if there's a better solution to this problem? In my real world problem the dataset is bigger and writing an if-statement is perhaps not an efficient solution. Can I use count in a better way?

```
iter= range(6)

start = 0.25
increase = 0.01

for count, i in enumerate(iter):
    print(count)
    if count in [1,3,5]:
        start = start + increase
        print(start)
```

Comment: `if count % 2 == 1:`

Comment: mmm 2 things: 1) for i in iter returns i=0, i=1,.... you don't need the enumerate (at least that iter is an example variable) 
2) you could check if the count is even  count%2 return the rest of int division so every second iteration will have values 1,3,5... `if count%2 :` will do the trick

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the operator `%` who tells you if it's even or odd:

```py
print(1%2)  # 1
print(2%2)  # 0
print(3%2)  # 1
print(4%2)  # 0
print(5%2)  # 1
```

In the case, you use counter:

```
for count, i in enumerate(iter):
    print(count)
    if count % 2:  # It gives only 1 or 0
        start += increase
        print(start)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could cycle between adding zero and your increment, and accumulate:

```
from itertools import cycle, accumulate, islice

length = 6
start = 0.25
increase = 0.01

xs = accumulate(cycle([0, increase]), initial=start)
for x in islice(xs, length):
    print(x)
```

Output:

```
0.25
0.25
0.26
0.26
0.27
0.27
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use zip to skip iterations:

```
iter6 = iter(range(6))

start = 0.25
increase = 0.01

for _,i in zip(iter6,iter6): 
    start += increase       # i is only every second value
```

there is also islice() in itertools:

```
for i in islice(iter6,1,None,2): 
    start += increase       # i is only every second value
```

Or sum with either of those:

```
start += sum(increase for _ in zip(iter6,iter6))
```